# Python AST - finding particular named function calls

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to analyse some Python code to identify where specific functions are being called and which arguments are being passed.

For instance, suppose I have an ML script that contains a `model.fit(X_train,y_train)`. I want to find this line in the script, identify what object is being fit (i.e., `model`), and to identify `X_train` and `y_train` as the arguments (as well as any others).

I'm new to AST, so I don't know how to do this in an efficient way.

So far, I've been able to locate the line in question by iterating through a list of child nodes (using `ast.iter_child_nodes`) until I arrive at the `ast.Call` object, and then calling its `func.attr`, which returns `"fit"`. I can also get `"X_train"` and `"y_train"` with `args`.

The problem is that I have to know where it is in advance in order to do it this way, so it's not particularly useful. The idea would be for it to obtain the information I'm looking for automatically.

Additionally, I have not been able to find a way to determine that `model` is what is calling `fit`.

Comment: There's no much you can do aside from walk the tree. It's not indexed. As for `model`, it's available from the `func` attribute of the same node that provided `fit`: `call_node.value.func.attr == "fit"` and `call_node.value.func.value.id == 'model'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the `ast` and search for `ast.Call` nodes where the name is `fit`:

```
import ast
def fit_calls(tree):
  for i in ast.walk(tree):
    if isinstance(i, ast.Call) and isinstance(i.func, ast.Attribute) and i.func.attr == 'fit':
       yield {'model_obj_str':ast.unparse(i.func.value),
              'model_obj_ast':i.func.value,
              'args':[ast.unparse(j) for j in i.args],
              'kwargs':{j.arg:ast.unparse(j.value) for j in i.keywords}}
```

Test samples:

```py
#https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model
sample_1 = """
model = tf.keras.models.Model(
   inputs=inputs, outputs=[output_1, output_2])
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="mse", metrics=["mae", "acc"])
model.fit(x, (y, y))
model.metrics_names
"""
sample_2 = """
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()
model.compile(optimizer, loss='mse', steps_per_execution=10)
model.fit(dataset, epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=10)
"""
sample_3 = """
x = np.random.random((2, 3))
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, (2, 2))
_ = model.fit(x, y, verbose=0)
"""
#https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html
sample_4 = """
estimator = estimator.fit(data, targets)
"""
sample_5 = """
y_predicted = SVC(C=100).fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
"""

print([*fit_calls(ast.parse(sample_1))])
print([*fit_calls(ast.parse(sample_2))])
print([*fit_calls(ast.parse(sample_3))])
print([*fit_calls(ast.parse(sample_4))])
print([*fit_calls(ast.parse(sample_5))])
```

Output:

```
[{'model_obj_str': 'model', 'model_obj_ast': <ast.Name object at 0x1007737c0>, 
  'args': ['x', '(y, y)'], 'kwargs': {}}]
[{'model_obj_str': 'model', 'model_obj_ast': <ast.Name object at 0x1007731f0>, 
  'args': ['dataset'], 'kwargs': {'epochs': '2', 'steps_per_epoch': '10'}}]
[{'model_obj_str': 'model', 'model_obj_ast': <ast.Name object at 0x100773d00>, 
  'args': ['x', 'y'], 'kwargs': {'verbose': '0'}}]
[{'model_obj_str': 'estimator', 'model_obj_ast': <ast.Name object at 0x100773ca0>, 
  'args': ['data', 'targets'], 'kwargs': {}}]
[{'model_obj_str': 'SVC(C=100)', 'model_obj_ast': <ast.Call object at 0x100773130>, 
  'args': ['X_train', 'y_train'], 'kwargs': {}}]
```